# Regex matching with yes/no

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to match yes/no with regex. Using "yes" as an example here: 
What I want the user to be able to put in is basically either y or Y followed by whatever characters.

What I've tried so far is `[Yy]\w+|[Yy]` and that works but, viewed with my not so experienced regex eyes, that looks a bit redundant?

Comment: Please add some sample strings that should match and some that shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the regular expressions:

- Yes: `^[Yy].*` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rljPq7/2)
- No: `^[Nn].*` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VU9uUv/2)

But I would suggest that it's better to just take the first character of a string, convert it to lower case, and check if it's either `y` or `n`. For example in JavaScript:

```js
const reply = "Yes";
const isItYes = reply[0].toLowerCase() === "y";  // <== true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Going on regexr.com, that expression matches only the letter Y. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The way easier thing would be to do as you said, but wanted to take the opportunity to learn a new thing or two :)

Comment: It's working [fine on regexr.com](https://regexr.com/5120u). Share a link to your regexr.com snippet, if you want more help debugging it.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I didn't activate the "multiline" flag. Thanks :)